# Java - Explanation Object File

Tags: java, file, object, arraylist

I need to create a ArrayList that will be written into a local object file.
But It's the **first** time I use File in java. So.. can anyone shortly explain me how to do that?

I just need to insert this ArrayList into the file (so write I think), read the file and use the previously arraylist stored in the same file.

I tried to implement it, and this is the result:

```
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("contiCorrenti");
    ObjectInputStream fileObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

    ArrayList<contoCorrente> contiCorrentiArray = (ArrayList<contoCorrente>) fileObjIn.readObject();

    fileObjIn.close();
    fileIn.close();

    contoCorrente c1 = new contoCorrente("IDNALFO", 14, 1);
    contoCorrente c2 = new contoCorrente("IDNALFO", 14, 3);

    contiCorrentiArray.add(c1);



    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("contiCorrenti");
    ObjectOutputStream fileObj = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

    fileObj.writeObject(contiCorrentiArray);
    fileObj.close();
    fileOut.close();
```

It will probably be all wrong, so I ask you to be understanding.

Comment: Are you getting error?

Comment: Yeah `Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException`

But otherwise is it right?

Comment: looks like error. I posted running code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119702/java-explanation-object-file/60120048#60120048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably file read error. Below should work. I created a dummy "contiCorrenti" class for testing. Note that this is very basic (and costly) serialization. You should probably look for better versions like kryo or fasterxml.

```
package io;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ObjectWrite {

    static class contoCorrente implements Serializable {

        public contoCorrente(String string, int k, int l) {
            name = string;
            i = k;
            j = l;
        }

        String name;
        int i;
        int j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<contoCorrente> contiCorrentiArray = null;
        File file = new File("contiCorrenti");
        if (file.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream fileObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            contiCorrentiArray = (ArrayList<contoCorrente>) fileObjIn.readObject();

            fileObjIn.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } else {
            contiCorrentiArray = new ArrayList<contoCorrente>();
        }

        System.out.println("Size of List at start: "+contiCorrentiArray.size());

        contoCorrente c1 = new contoCorrente("IDNALFO", 14, 1);
        contoCorrente c2 = new contoCorrente("IDNALFO", 14, 3);

        contiCorrentiArray.add(c1);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream fileObj = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        fileObj.writeObject(contiCorrentiArray);
        fileObj.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class ObjectWrite
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ObjectWrite`

Comment: I am able to run it. Can you check if package declaration is correct and it is compiling? You can always copy individual code sniplet (specifically read related) and put on your running code and test. Let me know.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ObjectWrite$contoCorrente at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)`

Comment: You can try to move internal static class contoCorrente to a separate java file and import it in this class and try running. Nevertheless, you can always copy my logic of read and write (not whole class) and put it in your existing class to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to output your ArrayList to a file correct? If so, this is how I do it:

```
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(**file path here**));
        os.write(Arrays.toString(contoCorrente.toArray()).getBytes(), 0, Arrays.toString(contoCorrente.toArray()).length());
```

Let me know if this works for you! :)

Comment: In addition to doing the output, I would like to read with the same array what is written in my previous output .. I don't know if I explain myself.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to write raw object data? I prefer human and machine readable text formats like CSV, XML, JSON or whatever. For each of them you will find libraries to read and write them.

Comment: @Stefan to be honest I need to create a mini bank system (just an homework). So, in any way, the bank accounts will have to be encrypted. (P.S. I can't even use the formats you listed)

Comment: @xAspired ah my apologies. So the file already exists and contains data that you want to read? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @pizza I created it but I don't know how to insert on it the arraylist that contains all the bank accounts. Subsequently, I will also need to know the relative information of the individuals bank account, so I will need to take the arraylist back from the file. Tell me if you didn't understand.